# How to click on the reCAPTCHA using webdriverio

Tags: javascript, node.js, automation, webdriver-io, wdio-v6

Hi everyone can you help me with that problem?
I'm trying to enter inside the iframe of google reCAPTCHA. Tried several ways to click but didn't work with the iframe it seems.

Appreciate your help. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

After digging deep, I got the solution, So you can't go ahead by solving reCAPTCHA, either you can white list the URL and use it in your code i.e how you can actually bypass reCAPTCHA.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It's Possible to click on the reCAPTCHA test version.  Of course, prod version of reCAPTCHA is much complicated to automate.

Test reCAPTCHA looks like this :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibpSB.png)

Here is the code.

```
const iframe = $('iframe[title="reCAPTCHA"]');

await iframe.click({ x: 30, y: 30 });
```